# What are some Innovative custom templates for Lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, app-builder, lightning-templates

Now that we have the `lightning:appHomeTemplate`, `lightning:recordHomeTemplate`, and `lightning:homeTemplate` interfaces, what are some of the innovative templates that we can create for Lightning Experience to really push the envelope of customizable user experiences?

Comment: So, your question didn't strike me immediately as meeting the appropriate format we expect here for Q&A (see [ask]), but I think it's in the spirit of what we try to do here. As such, I went ahead and put the question into the question area, and your answer as a Community Wiki so it can indeed be a "mega-list" of potentially useful information. I hope I didn't go too far off-base, though, so please review my edit and make any additional changes you'd like.

Comment: Seems fair. I would still include the part about mentioning any other collections that are found. Obviously as a bleeding edge new feature there aren't many in the wild yet. But I'm sure there will be soon enough.

Answer (score 1):

The expandable template from the "Pure Aloe" demo app used at Dreamforce '17 is a 2-column template with an "expand" button that hides the right pane and expands the left.
https://github.com/dreamforce17/purealoe/tree/master/force-app/main/default/aura/expandTemplate

---

Comment: Has anyone else seen interesting templates since Dreamforce? It would be great if there were a whole library of them or such. Or even just examples that imitate the existing standard layouts so you can play and adapt them to your needs.