# How to apply Dashboard to full Screen in Lightning App Builder Page?

Tags: lightning, dashboard, app-builder

I am creating a new `lightning App Builder` Home Page. on login of user he need to see his Dashboard, now user is seeing his Dashboard. but my problem is Dashboard is Not apply entire screen. Below i have attached the Screen please let me know any work around for this.
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You can  create a custom Home Template for this scenario. Refer this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/199834/what-are-some-innovative-custom-templates-for-lightning[link][1]

Comment: @vignesh can you explain me in detail ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hereby attached the code-Snippet for your reference.

**After you created the component**:

1. Go to AppBuilder --> Select HomePage --> The Custom Component that you have created is listed on --> then select that.

**Component:**

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:homeTemplate" access="global" >

    <aura:attribute name="dashboard" type="Aura.Component[]" access="global"/>

    <div aura:id="container">

        <lightning:layout >
            <lightning:layoutItem aura:id="dashboard" size="12" class="dashboard">
                {!v.dashboard}
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>

    </div>

</aura:component>
```

Design:

```
<design:component label="One column layout">
    <flexipage:template >
        <flexipage:region name="dashboard" defaultWidth="MEDIUM">
            <flexipage:formfactor type="MEDIUM" width="LARGE" />
        </flexipage:region>
    </flexipage:template>
</design:component>
```